# What Kenesis keyboard cable is this?

Tags: keyboard, cable

I have a broken Kenesis freestyle solo keyboard. The keyboard is separated into two as shown here:

[image]

I cut the linking cable so I need a new one. Here is a picture of the cable:

[image]

what type of cable is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a custom 20-conductor cable. Unless you can figure out the exact connector model so that you can wire your own replacement, you should consider contacting [Kinesis](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/contact.htm) for a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Could you also try joining the cable back together? Depending on how much a new connector is worth/if it is available, it may be worth an hour of your time with a multimeter and some electrical tape...

Comment: You can also use a soldering iron to join the wires.

Comment: If you don't know how to solder, take it by the nearest college's electrical engineering department (bring pizza to barter).